# Making Straw in Blender

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

I need to recreate this product and am not sure on how to model the straw inside the box.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stick?

Comment: Is this question about ideas or about how to use hair particles? (see question tags).
You can make straw really easy with hair particles.  
Another idea is to use cloth simulation with a few obstacles.

Comment: Ultimately we went without the straw, but I think it's an interesting problem to solve regardless. 

In my limited experience with hair particles, making something this chaotic just felt unachievable, but like I said, my experience in that area is very limited.

I considered making the straw using splines and just getting my hands dirty making it all manually, but I felt like there must be an easier way. Appreciate you guys taking the time to look at my question, sorry for not being clearer!